# to pass array values in email body of message

Tags: php, email, joomla, components

```
Array
(
    [id] => 
    [name] => hjkjh
    [email] => hjkhjk@gail.zfcc
    [address] => fsdf
    [gender] => female
    [city] => MUMBAI
    [hobbies] => Array
        (
            [0] => dance
            [1] => reading
        )

    [myimage] => 
)
```

I want to passs this values in body of email msg 
how to pass the VALUES
this array is in $data
I want as this

```
name = value
email= value
```

Can someone please help

Comment: Loop through it -> Convert to string you want -> Send string in email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as

```
$name = $your_array["name"];
$email = $your_array["email"];
$address = $your_array["address"];
$gender = $your_array["gender"];
$city = $your_array["city"];
$hobbies = '';

foreach($your_array["hobbies"] as $key=>$val){
  $hobbies .= $val.' ';
}
```

And finally you can use the above variables in the email code.

Update from your last comment, you can do the way you are doing as

```
    foreach($data as $key=>$value) { 
    $body .=$key."="; 
    if($key== 'hobbies'){
        foreach($value as $k=>$v){
            $body .= $v.' ';
        }
        $body .= "\n";
    }else{
            $body .=$value."\n"; 
    }

} 
$body .= "\n";
```

Comment: foreach($data as $key=>$value)
  {
         $body .=$key."=";
   $body .=$value."\n";
   
  
  }

  $body .= "\n";
  
  
  $body=print_r($body,true);
  
  $mailer->setBody($body);
  $mailer->setSubject('Your subject string');
  $send = $mailer->Send();

Comment: have to do it something like this

Comment: got all values except hobby

Comment: can you tell me if i follow your method how can i pass all the values in $body

Comment: well if you follow your way thats also correct, you need to do another loop for hobby inside the first loop since hobbies values are again in an array

Comment: Check my updated answer to get hobbies using your way of looping the array.

Comment: this worked thank you lotsi m working in joomla and i want to add unique field to email any idea?

Comment: Unique field ? I did not understand could you explain a bit ?

Comment: there is form in which i fill all this values name,email etc when i press a button save and close , there is parent save() function which save my values automatically to database . when i call the parent save () function i want to check for unique email id to be stored i database and then sent mail , send mail is working all fine  but if i call parent save() function first the mail is not sent.

Comment: I suppose there is something in that function which is breaking the code. You need to debug that piece of code to see if something is going wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

Check this :

```
$data=array(
    "id" =>1, 
    "name" => "hjkjh",
    "email" => "hjkhjk@gail.zfcc",
    "address" => "fsdf",
    "gender" =>  "female",
    "city" => "MUMBAI",
    "hobbies" => Array
        (
         0 => "dance",
         1 => "reading"
         ),
    "myimage" => ""
);

$body="";
$body.="Name :".$data['name']."<br/>";
$body.="Email :".$data['email']."<br/>";
$body.="Address :".$data['address']."<br/>";
$body.="Gender :".$data['gender']."<br/>";
$body.="City :".$data['city']."<br/>";
$body.="Hobbies :".$data['hobbies'][0].", ".$data['hobbies'][1]."<br/>";
echo $body;
```

And Its O/P is as given:-

```
Name :hjkjh
Email :hjkhjk@gail.zfcc
Address :fsdf
Gender :female
City :MUMBAI
Hobbies :dance, reading
```

I Hope this is what you are needed!

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = implode( ", ",$array);
```

will work.... visit the link http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/233154-printing-out-a-php-array-in-an-email-body/ for details ........thanks

Comment: You could include in your answer the code block instead of sharing a forum post.